# Isn't using eval() with a dictionary a better way in this case?

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

The two functions below perform an arithmetic operation on two integers and return an integer result.

I've heard a lot about eval() being really bad to use because it can cause many problems. But taking a look at the code I've written below, it seems that eval() spares many lines of code, right?

```
def dict_calculate(operation, num1, num2):
    operations = {'add': '+', 'subtract': '-', 'multiply': '*', 'divide': '//'}
    return eval(str(num1) + operations[operation] + str(num2))

def conditional_calculate(operation, num1, num2):
    if operation == 'add':
        return num1 + num2
    if operation == 'subtract':
        return num1 - num2
    if operation == 'multiply':
        return num1 * num2
    if operation == 'divide':
        return num1 // num2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 10
    y = 5

    print(str(dict_calculate('add', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(dict_calculate('subtract', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(dict_calculate('multiply', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(dict_calculate('divide', x, y)))

    print(str(conditional_calculate('add', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(conditional_calculate('subtract', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(conditional_calculate('multiply', x, y)) + ', ', end='')
    print(str(conditional_calculate('divide', x, y)))
```

Outputs are the same for both functions

```
15, 5, 50, 2
15, 5, 50, 2
```

Isn't eval best to use in this type of case? If not, is there a better way than eval() to achieve this same type of code-efficiency?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Will you properly sanitise/validate all user input to ensure you're not eval'ing something which has bad side effects…?

Comment: Take a look at the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), or define your own functions for each operator. Functions are just objects, you can store them in a dictionary.

Comment: @deceze I see what you mean... Is there any way to avoid that without writing many if statements?

Comment: And you should never let the number of lines of a solution determine if it is suitable or not. It could be *one factor*, but don't let that excuse the use of `eval()`.

Comment: Understood, thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import operator
def dict_calculate(operation, num1, num2):
    operations = {'add': operator.add,
                  'subtract': operator.sub,
                  'multiply': operator.mul,
                  'divide': operator.floordiv}
    return operations[operation](num1, num2)
```

If you don't want to import another module, you can do this:

```
def dict_calculate(operation, num1, num2):
    operations = {'add': '__add__',
                  'subtract': '__sub__',
                  'multiply': '__mul__',
                  'divide': '__floordiv__'}
    return getattr(num1, operations[operation])(num2)
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer. That is much more secure than using `eval()`, because here you reduce the possible operations to actual arithmetic operations, instead of allowing the user to do _anything_ by using eval (like deleting/modifying files, etc.)

Comment: Amazing, so I guess the wisdom here is to just use helper functions with dictionaries rather than evaluating string versions of operators directly. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you keep the original operator names instead of more or less arbitrary aliases, you can even do `getattr(operator, operation)(num1, num2)`…

Comment: @deceze I was thinking just the same :-)

Comment: and for more complex/weird operations you can use lambdas:


    operations = {
        ...
        "addition_plus_one": (lambda x, y: x + y + 1),
        ...